# Unable to search old data(data before server restart) using lucene search. what could be the reason?

Tags: java, search, lucene

i am using lucene-core-2.9.2.jar for full text search for my website.

I have created a record in mywebsite called 'Entry1' and searched in the search bar for the same using its ID. i got the result,i.e., i am able to search for the record 'Entry1'.

Then i stopped my server and restarted it. Now i searched for 'Entry1' record. But this time it returned no results. what could be the reason?

I copied the database from other server. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my database is moved from one server to another. The lucene indexes were gone. So i have created new lucene index files for the database. To do so, I run the following  block of code.

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(standardEntity.class).batchSizeToLoadObjects( 1000 )
        .cacheMode( CacheMode.IGNORE ).threadsToLoadObjects( 20 ).threadsForSubsequentFetching( 50 )
        .startAndWait();        
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```